# What is fastest way to display a .Net fastline graph of magnitude vs. time that scrolls leftward a fixed n number of points?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My current method is too slow and graph lags behind new points...
For each new point, .RemoveAt() removes the oldest and .AddXY adds the newest.
(X is time, Y is magnitude).
 There are 3,600 new points per second.

I'm planning to do this, unless there is a faster method...
For each new point, append it to circular buffer, clear the graph, and plot n latest points from buffer.

Is there an even faster method?

Comment: _There are 3,600 new points per second_ Wow! do you really have a monitor that can display all those points?

Comment: Actually, the 3,600 points contain 24 channels of data, so that's 150 points on the x-axis and 24 different functions, all roughly horizontally parallel.  I've used .Net's fastline since 2007 when it could handle 8,000 points per second.  Don't know what it is now.